# iOS Draw n number of bar graph Dynamically using core plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I used core plot and it's working very well but ..there are problem now,
    i have to draw n number Bars in single plot space dynamically...it may be 2 or 3 or 5 or non.

i am able to create multiple instance of the Bar ..but where i set the identifier dynamically and how handle every bar draw calculation in side delegate.
My Code snippet is below.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
if([plot.identifier isEqual:kBarIdentifier1])
 {
   //....getting data from array and return .
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still at a higher level but i will try to answer as per my understanding:

- *where i set the identifier dynamically* : You can have some constants strings which you can use for setting identifiers. If you want to make it completely dynamic take a counter and use it's value to set as identifier like:

  ```
  plot.identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];
  ```

  Create the plot inside a loop as per dynamic req. and just after creating instance set the identifier as per counter.
- *how handle every bar draw calculation in side delegate* : This is not so clear what you want to know. This method is called according to count you will pass in delegate method:

  ```
    -(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plotnumberOfRecords {
  return someCount;
  }
  ```

  The delegate method  "numberForPlot" will be called for each plot as per someCount. Identify the plot & take value from some array and return the value.

//edit:

```
  -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:     (NSUInteger)index
   {
    if (fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip) {
     //compare identifiers from a list of identifier maintained
     if ([plot.identifier isEqual:identifier1]) {
        return value;//get value from some array having values for plot identifier1
    }        
    ///and so on for all identifiers

    } 

    if(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlot)//not sure on enum please check 
     {
         //handle similar to above one
     }
  }
```

Comment: on  second point.i m drawing bar and scatter both inside one graph plot now i have to draw dynamically both ..inside delegate method , using identifier i m fetching data from array and return.so suppose i have big Dictionary with in Array with multiple bar graph data ,i set identifier for each one .so how i use these identifier inside delegate to draw exact draw bar or scatter as per as i get value from server.

Comment: You want to combine bar chart and scatter chart ,not sure whether you should do like that. For the fetching of data as you told it's difficult to guess your data model but i have given some explanation in edits.